# org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations, Wanted 1 time, But was 2 times

Tags: android, kotlin

hello I'm having trouble testing with a viewmodel like this, how do I make a test with a viewmodel like this because i've had an error several times. where I explained the error below

```
class SignUpViewModel(private val pref: Repository) : ViewModel() {
val registerResponse: LiveData<RegisterResponse> = pref.registerResponse
val toastText: LiveData<String> = pref.toastText

fun registerAccount(name: String, email: String, password: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        pref.registerAccount(name, email, password)
    }
}}
```

this is the test i made but it failed and i don't know where the error is... for the tests I did using the repositor and viewmodel

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class SignUpViewModelTest {
@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@get:Rule
var mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()



@Mock
private lateinit var repository: Repository
private lateinit var signUpViewModel: SignUpViewModel

private val dummyRegisterResponse = DataDummy.generateDummyRegisterResponse()
private val dummyName = "Full Name"
private val dummyEmail = "email@mail.com"
private val dummyPassword = "password"

@Before
fun setUp() {
    signUpViewModel = SignUpViewModel(repository)
}

@Test
fun standartTest() = runTest {
    val obj = MutableLiveData<RegisterResponse>()
    obj.value = dummyRegisterResponse
    repository.registerAccount(dummyName, dummyEmail, dummyPassword)
    Mockito.`when`(repository.registerResponse).thenReturn(obj)
    signUpViewModel.registerAccount(dummyName, dummyEmail,dummyPassword)
    val actualResponse = signUpViewModel.registerResponse
    verify(repository).registerAccount(dummyName, dummyEmail, dummyPassword)
    Assert.assertNotNull(actualResponse)
    Assert.assertEquals(dummyRegisterResponse, actualResponse)
}}
```

after testing the code above, the results are like this and the error is like this and the error is like this. I'm confused where is the error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations:
repository.registerAccount(
"Full Name",
"email@mail.com",
"password");
Wanted 1 time:
-> at com.example.mysubmission_intermediate.Remote.Repository.registerAccount(Repository.kt:62)
But was 2 times:
-> at SignUpViewModelTest$standartTest$1.invokeSuspend(SignUpViewModelTest.kt:50)
-> at com.example.mysubmission_intermediate.UI.SignUpViewModel$registerAccount$1.invokeSuspend(SignUpViewModel.kt:16)
```

this is the repository i am using and connected to the viewmodel i am using

```
class Repository private constructor(
private val pref: UserPreference,
private val apiService: ApiService
) {
private val _registerResponse = MutableLiveData<RegisterResponse>()
val registerResponse: LiveData<RegisterResponse> = _registerResponse
    fun registerAccount(name: String, email: String, password: String) {
    val client = apiService.userRegister(name, email, password)client.enqueue(object: Callback<RegisterResponse> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<RegisterResponse>,
            response: Response<RegisterResponse>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() !=null) {
                _registerResponse.value = response.body()
                _toastText.value = response.body()?.message
            } else {
                _toastText.value = response.message().toString()
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${response.message()}, ${response.body()?.message.toString()}" )

            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<RegisterResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            _toastText.value = t.message.toString()
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ${t.message.toString()}")
        }
    })
}
```

and this is dummy data that i use for testing

```
object DataDummy {
fun generateDummyRegisterResponse(): RegisterResponse {
    return RegisterResponse(
        false,
        "success"
    )
}}
```

please help me how can i solve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verify call of `verify(repository).registerAccount(dummyName, dummyEmail, dummyPassword)` checks that registerAccount is called exactly once.  It isn't-  it's called twice.  What you need to decide is if calling it twice is ok or not.  If it's ok, use `verify(repository, atLeastOnce())` which will pass if its called at least 1 time (but can be more often).

If its not ok and you really want it once-  you need to figure out why it was called twice.  The two calls were

```
at SignUpViewModelTest$standartTest$1.invokeSuspend(SignUpViewModelTest.kt:50)
-> at com.example.mysubmission_intermediate.UI.SignUpViewModel$registerAccount$1.invokeSuspend(SignUpViewModel.kt:16)
```

Figure out which is wrong, and fix either your test or code so it doesn't happen